# Left joining a table to itself with no WHERE clause results in fewer rows than the original

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have a table (`table_old`) with a column (`person_id`) that sometimes has duplicate values.  I want to add a column that has a the maximum value of `age_at_midmonth` for each value of `person_id`.  `Table_old` has 27,236,296 rows.  `Table_new` has 27,209,850 rows.  The number of rows should not decrease since this is a `LEFT JOIN` with no `WHERE` clause.  What is happening here?  Am I doing this wrong?  Is there a better way?  The query is running in Oracle.

```
    create table schema1.table_new as
        select 
            t1.*, 
            t2.current_age
        from 
            schema1.table_old t1
            left join (
                select person_id, max(age_at_midmonth) as current_age
                from schema1.table_old
                group by person_id
            ) t2
                on t1.person_id = t2.person_id;
```

Comment: A LEFT JOIN shouldn't return less rows.

Comment: I'm curious about why this question was voted down.  I understand that I was making a dumb mistake here, but I thought the question itself was fairly well written and clear.  I'm not mad or anything, just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

I know this wasn't your actual question, but you don't actually even need to do a `LEFT JOIN` for that example.  It would be easier to just use analytical functions instead of the aggregate as part of a subquery.  For instance, your example query could be turned into:

```sql
SELECT t.*, 
       MAX(t.age_at_midmonth) OVER (PARTITION BY t.person_id) AS CURRENT_AGE
FROM schema1.table_old t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I was looking at the number of rows using the Analyze Table feature and then looking at the Stats/Size info for the table using Toad for Oracle.  It appears that running Analyze Table does not necessarily produce an accurate count of rows.  When I did `select count(*) from table_new;` and the same for `table_old`, I got the exact same number of rows.  Oops.